# Variables de entorno en Vercel

Tags: angular, typescript, vercel

estoy intentando desplegar un proyecto de angular, en el cuál tengo las siguientes variables de entorno

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    url: 'http://localhost:4200',
    client_id: 'aa',
    client_secret: 'bbb',
};
```

En Vercel las he añadido en su configuración, como variables de entorno (no he añadido la de production, y la de url apunta a la url del servidor), el problema es que me tira el error de que no encuentra ninguna de las variables de entorno.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he estado indagando y a falta de poder lanzar el comando ts-node en Vercel, lo tengo solucionado.

1. He creado el fichero `.env`
2. En el `package.json` he creado un config, un build y un serve specificos para generar los ficheros environment cuando me sean necesarios

```
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "config": "ts-node ./src/config-env.ts",
        "start-vercel": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng serve",
        "build-vercel": "npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
    }
```

`config-env.ts`

```
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();
const { argv } = require('yargs');
const environment = argv.environment;

let apiURL;
let targetPath;
if (environment === 'prod') {
    apiURL = process.env.URL;
    targetPath = `./src/environments/environment.prod.ts`;
} else {
    apiURL = process.env.URL_DEV;
    targetPath = `./src/environments/environment.ts`;
}

const envConfigFile = `
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    url: "${apiURL}",
    client_id: "${process.env.CLIENT_ID}",
    client_secret: "${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}" };`;

fs.writeFile(targetPath, envConfigFile, function (err: any) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Con esto básicamente lo que se hace es generar el fichero `environment.ts` o el ```environment.prod.ts`` de forma dinámica cada vez que lanzas el comando.

Si alguien tiene información sobre como poder leer las variables de entorno directamente del fichero `.env` me sería de mucha ayuda, pero por lo que he leído no es posible consultarlas en compilación